# How to display popover around pressed message? | Flyerchat | React Native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, popover

I am using flyerhq https://github.com/flyerhq/react-native-chat-ui for the chat function.

I want to display popover around the pressed message.

Below is the code to display chat messages and get a long-press event.

```
 <FlyerHQChat
        onMessageLongPress={(messageInfo: MessageType.Any) => {
          setMessageDetails(messageInfo);
          setOpen(true);
        }}
    ....
  />
```

Here is the code for popover

```
<TouchableOpacity ref={touchable}>
        
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Popover
        from={touchable}
        isVisible={open}
        onRequestClose={() => setOpen(false)}
        arrowSize={{ height: 0, width: 0 }}>
       
                <Text>This is popover </Text>
       
      </Popover>
```

Currently, a popover displayed on top of the screen

Here is a link to the demo https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wAzKMevRBXeWM9AZVVAv9c4WN8xUUuy9/view

Image of the current Popover

[image: Popover demo for chat]